# HWX 2.6 sandbox in virtual box - not able to start services

Tags: hdfs, sandbox, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

HWX 2.6 sandbox in virtual box - not able to start services (HDFS or ANY services using Ambari).

1. Vt-x enabled.
2. Server didnt start and timed out so increased timeout in "/etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties" - server.startup.web.timeout=180 - WORKS NOW.
3. As hdfs user - safe mode is OFF as well using command - hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
4. yum update and yum install -y hadooplzo hadooplzo-native done as well.
5. Can see the below in /etc/hosts

172.17.0.2      sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com sandbox-hdp

127.0.0.1 sandbox.hortonworks.com

Connection refused error :

[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# telnet sandbox.hortonworks.com 8020
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# telnet sandbox.hortonworks.com 8080 (WORKS)
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to sandbox.hortonworks.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

ambari-agent.log

INFO 2018-06-18 09:59:06,502 NetUtil.py:70 - Connecting to https://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8440/ca
ERROR 2018-06-18 09:59:06,569 NetUtil.py:96 - [Errno 8] _ssl.c:492: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
ERROR 2018-06-18 09:59:06,571 NetUtil.py:97 - SSLError: Failed to connect. Please check openssl library versions.
Refer to: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1022468 for more details.
WARNING 2018-06-18 09:59:06,576 NetUtil.py:124 - Server at https://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...

Answer (score -1):

Just faced the same issue while building up a HDP sandbox from scratch with Ansible. The solution was to add this line in `/etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini`

```
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
```

also you may need `verify=disable` in  `/etc/python/cert-verification.cfg` but not sure